# Table doesn't position in point of text indicate by code

Tags: tables, positioning

I'm new in Latex. I'm writing my thesis and i have this situation:

```
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext**:**
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center} 
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{gray!50}
     \bfseries Specifiche Tecniche & \bfseries Bluetooth BR & \bfseries Bletooth Low Energy \\
     \hline
     Frequenza & Tra $2400$ e $2483.5$ MHz & Tra $2400$ e $2483.5$ MHz \\
     \hline
     Data Channel & $79$ & $37$ \\
     \hline
     Advertising Channel & $32$ & $3$ \\
     \hline
     Criptaggio & $64/128 bit$ & AES $128$ bit \\
     \hline
     Range & $100$ m & $> 100$m \\
     \hline
     Throughput & $0.7-2.1$ Mbit/s & $< 0.3$ Mbit/s \\
     \hline
     Latenza di Connessione &   $ \approx 100$ ms   & $6$ ms \\
     \hline
     Tempo minimo di invio dati & $100$ ms & $3$ ms \\
     \hline
     Potenza di consumo & $1$ W & Tra $0.01$ a $0.5$ W \\
     \hline
     Picco di corrente  & $22-40$ mA & $10-30$ mA \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Differenze tra Bluetooth BR \& Bluetooth 4.0]{Differenze tra Bluetooth BR \& Bluetooth 4.0}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{center}
\end{table} \\
othertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertextothertext.
```

The problem is that i would the table in this point, by the compiler position this at the beginning of the next page.

(PS: sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you read the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001) To save some (vertical) space, replace `\begin{center}` with `\centering` and delete `\end{center}`. Then, check if replacing `\begin{table}[h]` with `\begin{table}[h!]` gets the job done.

Comment: thanks Mico, i read this now. Meanwhile i'm trying tour tips but doesn't work

Comment: Note that the only reason for the `table` environment is to allow latex to move the table to help with page breaking. that is why floating environments have captions so that you can reference them when they are _not_ in the normal text flow.

Comment: it's usually a good idea to input tables in vertical mode.  add a blank line before the table and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want tabular material to "float" (in the LaTeX sense of the word), don't encase it in a floating environment such as `table`. Do learn to live with LaTeX's float placement algorithm -- more often than not, it is very good. If you must, provide the `[h!]` positioning specifier. If the table still won't fit on the page, there probably just isn't enough space left on that page to fit the table.

I have two additional suggestions:

- Omit all vertical lines and most horizontal lines from the tabular material, and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to draw the remaining horizontal lines.
- Use the `\num` and `\SI` macros of the `siunitx` package to denote scalar numbers and numbers with units, respectively.

The results of making these adjustments are shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[binary-units,per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt} % default: 6pt
\centering % not '\begin{center}...\end{center}'
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\rowcolor{gray!30}
\bfseries Specifiche Tecniche & \bfseries Bluetooth BR & \bfseries Bluetooth Low Energy \\ 
\addlinespace

Frequenza  & \num{2400}--\SI{2483.5}{\mega\hertz} &  \num{2400}--\SI{2483.5}{\mega\hertz} \\

Data Channel & 79 & 37 \\

Advertising Channel & 32 & 3 \\

Criptaggio & \SI{64/128}{\bit} & AES \SI{128}{\bit} \\

Range & \SI{100}{\meter} & ${}>\SI{100}{\meter}$ \\

Throughput & \num{0.7}--\SI{2.1}{\mega\bit\per\second} & ${}< 0.3$ Mbit/s \\

Latenza di Connessione & ${}\approx \SI{100}{\milli\second}$  & \SI{6}{\milli\second} \\

Tempo minimo di invio dati & \SI{100}{\milli\second} & \SI{3}{\milli\second} \\

Potenza di consumo & \SI{1}{\watt} & \num{0.01}--\SI{0.5}{\watt} \\

Picco di corrente  & \num{22}--\SI{40}{\milli\ampere} & \num{10}--\SI{30}{\milli\ampere} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[Differenze tra Bluetooth BR e Bluetooth 4.0]{Differenze tra Bluetooth BR e Bluetooth 4.0}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVE]
Thanks to guide sharelatex https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Positioning_images_and_tables - section Positioning tables I have used the param H instead h! suggested by Mico. For this my new code is:

```
 \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
     \hline
     \rowcolor{gray!50}
     \bfseries Specifiche Tecniche & \bfseries Bluetooth BR & \bfseries Bletooth Low Energy \\
     \hline
     Frequenza & Tra $2400$ e $2483.5$ MHz & Tra $2400$ e $2483.5$ MHz \\
     \hline
     Data Channel & $79$ & $37$ \\
     \hline
     Advertising Channel & $32$ & $3$ \\
     \hline
     Criptaggio & $64/128 bit$ & AES $128$ bit \\
     \hline
     Range & $100$ m & $> 100$m \\
     \hline
     Throughput & $0.7-2.1$ Mbit/s & $< 0.3$ Mbit/s \\
     \hline
     Latenza di Connessione &   $ \approx 100$ ms   & $6$ ms \\
     \hline
     Tempo minimo di invio dati & $100$ ms & $3$ ms \\
     \hline
     Potenza di consumo & $1$ W & Tra $0.01$ a $0.5$ W \\
     \hline
     Picco di corrente  & $22-40$ mA & $10-30$ mA \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Differenze tra Bluetooth BR \& Bluetooth 4.0]{Differenze tra Bluetooth BR \& Bluetooth 4.0}
\label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}
```

best regards and thank you all

Comment: You will sooner or later see, that this is not good solution but source of new problems. Far better is Mico solution. With `[H]` you actually jeopardize basic  precedence of LaTeX ...